# How to silently install any software across all my office computers?

Tags: windows-7, installation

How to silently install any software across all my office computers? All my office computers have Windows 7 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Is this a domain environment?

Comment: Not enough information and too broad anyway.  GPOs, scripts, software deployment platforms (like SCCM) imaging platforms, even really quiet helpdesk guys can "silently install any software" across all your office computers.

Comment: "really quiet helpdesk guys". Funny. They're the ones dressed in all black that stealthily install software on your computer while you're bending down to pick up the pencil you dropped on the floor.

Comment: Yes @ScottChamberlain, this is a domain environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a domain the standard procedure is to use Group Policy. Here is the [Microsoft Knowledgeable article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102) showing how to set it up.

Here are the Assign a package steps. so your software will be silently installed next reboot

> 1. Start the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in. To do this, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click
>      Active Directory Users and Computers.
> 2. In the console tree, right-click your domain, and then click Properties.
> 3. Click the Group Policy tab, select the policy that you want, and then click Edit.
> 4. Under Computer Configuration, expand Software Settings.
> 5. Right-click Software installation, point to New, and then click Package.
> 6. In the Open dialog box, type the full Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path of the shared installer package that you want. For example,
>      \file server\share\file name.msi.
>
>    **Important Do not use the Browse button to access the location. Make sure that you use the UNC path of the shared installer package.**
> 7. Click Open.
> 8. Click Assigned, and then click OK. The package is listed in the right-pane of the Group Policy window.
> 9. Close the Group Policy snap-in, click OK, and then close the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in.
> 10. When the client computer starts, the managed software package is automatically installed.

Comment: How about for .exe? or for vbscripts?

Comment: @BenjaminJones you don't "install" a exe (make them show up in Add/Remove Programs), you just copy them to their destination. Same for vbscripts. For those just set up a group policy one time action to copy the files from a network share to the target computer.

Comment: be sure to add any arguments for installations options that appear during the install

Answer (score 2):

And if you're not in a domain, just use something like [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to start [msiexec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) remotely with the correct command line parameters to install silently packages you need and log results on a file you can read later to verify the operation.